# Accessing Kubernetes / Kubernetes API using KubernetesDotNet

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, kubernetes, x509certificate, kubernetes-security

I'm running a webAPI application that is actually using KubernetesDotNet **[or other clients]** to connect to a remote Kubernetes cluster API.

Locally is working, but once I publish in the server I started receiving

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

The connection is stablished reading a .pfx file.

```cs
IKubernetesClient k8sClient = new SslClientConfiguration
{
    ClusterUri = new Uri(
                        "https://remotekubernetes.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io"),
    Certificate = new X509Certificate2(
        HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "certificate.pfx",
                    "12345608765422", 
                    X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet)
}.CreateClient( AuthType.SSLAuth);
```

That cert I get it using the `.kube/config` file information, nevertheless I have also tested locally this

```cs
IKubernetesClient k8sClient = new KubeConfigClientConfiguration(
    HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "config"
    ).CreateClient(AuthType.SSLAuth);
```

Accessing a copy of the `.kube/config` and is also working fine.

The thing is that once I publish the webApi application I start receiving the SSL errors.

How to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a CA, cert issue. What ca.pem or ca are you using in your server app?

Comment: I'm converting the certs to .cer and .pfx files that are the supported file types for an Azure App Service.

Comment: Yeah but does kubernetes support that format? you are connecting to the kube-apiserver...

Comment: Running the webapp in a  local development server + remote kubernetes  is working. Same app + certs, same remote kubernetes but webApp in server /azure websiteL it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you have a property to specify the CA? In kube config, notice that you have 2 sections: one that specifies the server CA and one that specifies the client certificate. Here you specified only the client certificate...